# TypeError: jQuery(...).carouFredSel is not a function

Tags: jquery

i have problem with start slider correctly.

TypeError: jQuery(...).carouFredSel is not a function.

I see on my source code that i have one instance off Jquery but Firebug tells that something is wrong.

Comment: have you added relevant javascript file.. show some code pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means [carouFredSel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/) jQuery plugin not integrated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `carouFredSel`, for me it was a case-sensitive problem. The file was being linked like this (I am using this with WordPress):

```
wp_enqueue_script('kopa-carouFredSel', $dir . '/js/jquery.caroufredsel-6.0.4-packed.js', array('jquery'), NULL, TRUE);
```

But everything worked when I changed it to:

```
wp_enqueue_script('kopa-carouFredSel', $dir . '/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js', array('jquery'), NULL, TRUE);
```

Notice the uppercase 'F' and 'S', just like the actual file name.

I hope this helps other people trying to integrate it into WordPress.